# javascript function not returning correct value

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have this function that checks a UK postcode.  The problem is that it never returns `true` or `false` - only `undefined`.

```
function PostcodeAnywhere_Interactive_FindByPostcode_v1_00(Key, Postcode, UserName) {

    var retval;

    $.getJSON("https://services.postcodeanywhere.co.uk/PostcodeAnywhere/Interactive/FindByPostcode/v1.00/json3.ws?",
    {
        Key: Key,
        Postcode: Postcode,
        UserName: UserName
    },
    function (response) {
        // Test for an error
        if (response.Items.length == 1 && typeof(response.Items[0].Error) != "undefined") {
            // Show the error message
            retval = false;
        } else {
            // Check if there were any items found
            if (response.Items.length == 0){
                retval = false;
            } else {
                retval = true;
            }
        }
    });

return retval;

}
```

To me it looks like it should always return `true` or `false`, so I can't understand where I'm going wrong.  Can someone please help?  Is it that the getJSON function needs time to execute?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return Value from inside of $.ajax() function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187201/return-value-from-inside-of-ajax-function) -- please use the search before you ask a question.

Comment: Anybody else read Nick Craver's blog post about SO storage requirements? I wonder how much of the disk array is taken up by questions like this? :-)

Comment: simply because you return retval before setting it (asynchronous)

Comment: Sorry everyone for posting a question already asked - I didn't realise that `$.getJSON` worked in a similar way as `$.ajax` and that it was therefore asynchronous

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return Value from inside of $.ajax() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187201/return-value-from-inside-of-ajax-function)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It returns undefined because `$.getJSON` runs asynchronously and for this reason retval is returned before the success function of `$.getJSON`  is executed. If you need to use `retval` you must call the function that uses it in the callback

```
   $.getJSON("https://services.postcodeanywhere.co.uk/PostcodeAnywhere/Interactive/FindByPostcode/v1.00/json3.ws?",
    {
        Key: Key,
        Postcode: Postcode,
        UserName: UserName
    },
    function (response) {
        // Test for an error
        if (response.Items.length == 1 && typeof(response.Items[0].Error) != "undefined") {
            // Show the error message
            retval = false;
        } else {
            // Check if there were any items found
            if (response.Items.length == 0){
                retval = false;
            } else {
                retval = true;
            }
            //use retval
            do_something_with_retval(retval);
        }
    });
```