# Call a ajax function within a function (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous

```
    function getCChatStatus() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.php?page=CChatAction",
        data: { action: "getStatus" }
    }).done(function(msg) {
        var cChatStatus = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);
        return cChatStatus;
    });
}

function CChatOptions() {
    var test = getCChatStatus();
    alert(test);
}
```

is returning "test is undefined".
How to solve this issue? I already tried async: false.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return Value from inside of $.ajax() function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187201/return-value-from-inside-of-ajax-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use asynchronous functions like jQuery.ajax, you will have to use callback functions to evaluate the results.

Thus, your getter has to be asynchronous:

```
function getCChatStatus(callback){
  jQuery.ajax({/*...*/})
  .done(function(){
     callback(jQuery.parseJSON(msg))
  })
}
```

And your test will have to look like:

```
function CChatOptions() {
  getCChatStatus(function(status){
    alert(status)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The ajax function is asynchronous and has'nt returned yet when you are calling the alert.

```
function getCChatStatus(callback) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.php?page=CChatAction",
        data: { action: "getStatus" }
    }).done(function(msg) {
        var cChatStatus = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);
        callback.call(cChatStatus);
    });
}

function CChatOptions() {
    getCChatStatus(function(test) {
        alert(test);
    });
}
```

You could also do:

```
function getCChatStatus() {
    var CChat = jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.php?page=CChatAction",
        data: { action: "getStatus" }
    });
    return CChat;
}

function CChatOptions() {
    var cChatStatus = getCChatStatus();
    cChatStatus.done(function(msg) {
        alert(jQuery.parseJSON(msg));
    });
}
```

Comment: 2nd one is working, first one does not seem to work. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Your `getCChatStatus()` function is not returning anything. Even with `async: false`, your function needs to return the return value of the `$.ajax()` call. Consider returning the actual observable object that you get from an async `$.ajax()` call and working with that, instead of running synchronous AJAX requests.

Answer (score -1):

**Try this should work !!**

```
 function getCChatStatus() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "index.php?page=CChatAction",
           success:function(msg){
            var cChatStatus = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);
            alert(cChatStatus); //if this alert works then that test will work..
            return cChatStatus;
        });
    }

    function CChatOptions() {
        var test = getCChatStatus();
        alert(test);
    }
```