# ajax data doesn't change

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I editted my ajax data but it still shows the old version while I am sure I saved it I even reopened the file and checked the location. It's like it is cached.

This is the actual code:

```
function setMessages(roomId, username, message){
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "http://www.sinansamet.nl/chatdistract/ajax/setMessages.php",
        data: { roomId:roomId, username:username, message:message },
        success: function(html) {
                  strReturn = html;
                }
        });
}
```

But what it sees is

```
function setMessages(id){
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "http://www.sinansamet.nl/chatdistract/ajax/setMessages.php",
        data: { id:id },
        success: function(html) {
                  strReturn = html;
                }
        });
}
```

Which was the old code.

The error is given in the console as "undefined id"

Comment: Ajax is Asynchronous. `return strReturn;` is happening before `strReturn = html;` happens.

Comment: Follow the post below for more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11576176/wait-for-a-jquery-ajax-callback-from-calling-function

Answer (score 2):

Do a browser refresh cache on most browsers it can be done by pressing CTRL + F5
Search google for clearing your browser cache.

Comment: Thanks I will try. I have a mac and I am on Safari I will look on google how to clear the cache of it

Comment: Oh actually the cache is on my phone. I am working with phonegap and this is in an application.

Answer (score 1):

the `a` in `ajax` stands for `asynchronous`.

the function is returning before the callback of the ajax call is being called.

Comment: Yea sorry forgot to remove that I had async on false before. But that wouldn't solve it anyway right?

Comment: No, but `async=false` is a very bad idea, it will freeze your page until the AJAX call returns

Comment: @SinanSamet can you update your question then with what you are actually using?

Comment: Exactly that but I forgot to remove the return in my script too. I'll remove it now.