# Ajax async false is deprecated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I am using jQuery 1.7 and I use `async:false` for my AJAX requets, but I've learned that this function is deprecated.

I need to use callback but this doesn't work:

```
$("#form").submit(function(e) {
var cnf;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    url: 'page.php', 
    data: $('#form').serialize(),
    async: true,
    success: function(responseText) { 
        if(responseText.indexOf('err') != -1) {
            cnf = "error";
        } 
        else {
            cnf = "success";
        }
        return callBack( cnf );
    }, 
    error: function() {
        cnf = "error";  
        return callBack( cnf ); 
    } 
});


if(cnf == "success")
{
   alert('ok');
}
});
```

The HTML:

```
<form id="form">
 <input type="text" name="email">
 <input type="submit">
</form>
```

If I use `async: false` this works. Using callBack I see the solution here: [wait for a jquery ajax callback from calling function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11576176/wait-for-a-jquery-ajax-callback-from-calling-function)

Comment: Anything that depends on the result of the AJAX call, *must* be in, called by, or (for events) attached by the callback of said AJAX call.

Comment: `async:false` is only deprecated when using deferred object method. To answer your issue, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: Ah yes is from 1.8 thanks you

Comment: SJAX was never a good idea.

Comment: `1)` Never use `async: false`. Ever. Period. Get to know and love your callbacks and `jQuery promises` `2)` Any arguments about this, please see `1)` :)

Comment: Thanks you Bergi and @TrueBlueAussie but who i can use callback ? With callBack(cnf) is not work u have a simple example plz ?

Comment: If you show the surrounding function for this code, we can provide an example. The code is incomplete. e.g. where is `callBack` defined?

Comment: Its all i have just in if() alert('ok') and $(form).submit(...) i need with this "if(cnf == "success")" i need to go step 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from the comments: You seem to be a little obsessed with *callbacks*, when you don't seem to need any! :)

The simple change to your existing code is to throw away `cnf` and simply put your code in the success part of the ajax call:

```
$("#form").submit(function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'page.php',
        data: $('#form').serialize(),
        async: true,
        success: function (responseText) {
            if (responseText.indexOf('err') != -1) {
                // Do something when it fails here
            } else {
                // Do something when it succeeds here!!!!
                alert('ok');
                // e.g. move on to "step 2"
            }
        },
        error: function () {
           // Do something when it fails here
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: i dont have complet my code but i need to change <form> if step 1 is good (like a paiement system) 1: email, 2 name and address

Comment: I have add all in one step :)

Comment: You need to show all your code to get a complete answer, but hopefully this has pointed you in the right direction.

Answer (score 5):

From the documentation:

> As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false **with jqXHR ($.Deferred)** is deprecated

You are not using it with `jqXHR`.

That said, non-async HTTP is horrible with JavaScript and best avoided. Do your work in or from the callback. Don't try to return data to the calling function so it can do the work.

Comment: I assume you meant "*sync HTTP is horrible*"?

Comment: Yes thanks you Quentin i dont see its from jqXhr im new in javascript / jquery i use this simple method for a contact form