# How can I check the inserted/edited item in jsgrid isn't duplicate?

Tags: javascript, php, jsgrid

I tried build custom validator for jsgrid that check the item.Name is really exist from DB or not before inserting or Editing to avoid any duplicated row.

the problem I read three times the Documents of jsgrid but I didn't get any idea how to fix the problem.

this work https://github.com/tabalinas/jsgrid-php helped me too much and I transformed to be useful for my work and to mysqli.

the idea:
I made function check DB if the value exist or not, if exist it return true else false in a php class

```
public function checkName($name){
    try{
        if(!empty($name)){
            $co_conn = $this->CON_conn->open_connect();
            $getsame = mysqli_query($co_conn,"select Name from category where Name = '$name'");
            if($getsame){
                $numit = mysqli_num_rows($getsame);
                if($numit > 0) return true;
                else return false;
            }
            else return true;
            $this->CON_conn->close_connect($co_conn);
        }
        else return true;
    }
    catch(Exception $er){
        return true;
    }
}
```

and I called this function in an external file "CheckValue.php"

```
<?php require_once '////the director of the class';
$chnow = new NameOfMyClass();
$result = true;
switch($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]) {
    case "CHGO":
        parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"), $_CHGO);
        //to ensure if it work i tested it.
        $result = $chnow->checkName($_CHGO["Name"]);
    break;
    default:
        $result = true;
    break;
}
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

in basic.html

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../bin/update.php"
    }).done(function(response) {
        response.unshift({ ID: "0", Name: "" });
        $("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
            height: "50%",
            width: "70%",
            selecting: false,
            filtering: false,
            editing: false,
            sorting: false,
            paging: true,
            autoload: true,
            pageSize: 15,
            pageButtonCount: 5,
            controller: {
                loadData: function(filter) {
                    return $.ajax({type:"GET", url: "../bin/update.php",data:filter});
                },
                updateItem: function(item) {
                    return $.ajax({type:"PUT",url: "../bin/update.php",data: item});
                },
                insertItem: function(item) {
                    /*$.ajax({type: "CHGO",url: "..bin/Checkvalue.php",data:item.Name, dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data){
                        JSON.parse(data);
                        consol.log(data);
                        //alert(data);
                        //I used many ways to find why its not work, then I commented it
                        }
                    });
                    //return $.ajax({type: "POST",url: "../bin/update.php",data: item});
                    //return data;

                            //else sweetAlert("error", "this value is exist!", "error");
                            //here I thought merge sweetalert js will give a good look of work not the normal message.
*/
                }
            },
            fields: [
                { name: "ID", type: "number",width: 50, editing:false, inserting:false },
                { name: "Name", type: "text", width: 50, validate: ["required",{
                        message: "this value is exist",
                        validator: function(value,item){
                            if(value != "")
                            {
                                $.ajax({
                                    type: "CHGO",
                                    url: "..bin/Checkvalue.php",
                                    data: item.Name,
                                    success: function(data){
                                        if(data == true) 
                                        //I assume here return the true/false to activate the error message but nothing work..sorry
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    } ]
                },
                { type: "control", modeSwitchButton: false, deleteButton: false }
            ]
       });
    });
    $(".config-panel input[type=checkbox]").on("click", function() {
        var $cb = $(this);
        $("#jsGrid").jsGrid("option", $cb.attr("id"), $cb.is(":checked"));
    });     
});
```

please help, I 'm try for 2 days to fix the problem.
thanks for the developers for writing the validate js file
I used jsgrid-1.4.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that `validate` supports only synchronous validation, and validation from our example requires ajax call, so it's asynchronous.

You have two options:

1. Load data to the client beforehand and validate inserting item on the client (so validation will be synchronous)
2. Validate insertion in `insertItem` method. Checkout the following issue to know more details https://github.com/tabalinas/jsgrid/issues/190

Comment: Sorry!, I tried it but didn't success; I think there is a problem in this
$.ajax({type: "CHGO",url: "..bin/Checkvalue.php",data:item.Name, dataType: "json"}); 
I change it to POST but really nothing

Comment: did you mean use async: false in ajax function

Comment: No, `async: false` is deprecated. What I meant in the first option is to do something like `$.ajax({ / * request to load existing items in DB */ }).done(function(existingItems) { $("#jsGrid").jsGrid( /* config of jsGrid with validate function, which will try to find value in existingItems before insert */ ) })`. Hope it's more clear.

Comment: I did this, I changed my work using `onItemInserting: function(args){}` still same,.... so I made little test returning value from Jquery.ajax like this: .......... 
 onItemInserting: function(args) {
if(args.item.Name != "") {
var dataa = function(){
var tmp = null;
$.ajax({type:"CHGO",url: "../bin/Checkvalue.php",data:({Name:args.item.Name}),success: function (data) {tmp = 123;}});return tmp;}();
if(dataa === 123){
args.cancel = true;
alert("Duplicated Value");}}},
........ what I got is (null)

Comment: And I supposed maybe should use `done() function` and didn't success

Comment: yes, `async: false` should help, but be aware it's deprecated http://stackoverflow.com/a/24187226/1140893

Comment: yes, but I used `success function` as what it wrote in jquery document
[http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) 
....... I used `done function` without `async` and didn't success ... and I used jquer 1.11

Comment: is that [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448011/jquery-ajax-methods-async-option-deprecated-what-now) good ?

Comment: finally, it returns true or false as what I want...........
`onItemInserting: function(args) {if(args.item.Name != "") {$.ajax({type:"CHGO",url: "../bin/Checkvalue.php",data:({Name:args.item.Name}),}).done(function(data){if(data === true){ args.cancel = true;swal("Error, Duplicated value");} });}},` ... but however when it return `true` it still inserting (i.e. `args.cancel' not work) ... why?