# How to trigger a function when all ajax finish?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

ajax request will be initiated by user click

It is impossible to know how many request will be sent

I tried ajaxComplete, but it is not work, I think it cannot detects ajax after the page loaded.

```
function ajax1() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'getCount.php',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
            var count = parseInt(data);
            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                ajax2();
            }
        }
    });
}

function ajax2() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'getCount2.php',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
            var count = parseInt(data);
            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                ajax3();
            }
        }
    });
}

function ajax3() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax3.php',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
            //do something
        }
    });
}
$(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, xhr, settings) {
    alert('Complete');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE: Really good read on promises: [Promises cookbook](https://github.com/mattdesl/promise-cookbook)

Normal way of doing that is using promises returned by `$.ajax` function.

Change your functions to return result of `.ajax` call:

```
function ajax1(..) { 
  return $.ajax(...)
}
```

Then use `$.when` to make new promise resolved when all promises are resolved.

```
$.when([ajax1(), ajax2(), ajax3()]).then(function() { alert('all complete') })
```

However in more complicated case (as is yours) you need to dynamically store references to all promises and only call `$.when` once all the promises added.

So for instance you can create to arrays of promises, one for `ajax2` calls and one for `ajax3` calls.

```
var ajax2calls = [], ajax3calls=[]  

function ajax1() {
  return $.ajax({
    url: 'getCount.php',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function (data) {
        var count = parseInt(data);
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            ajax2calls.push(ajax2());
        }

        $.when(ajax2calls).then(function() {
            $.when(ajax3calls).then(function() {
               alert('all done')
            }
        })

    }
  });
}
```

Also, you might want to consider using [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md) promise library, as it provides a lot more rich API than regular promise/A or promise/A+. Check `map`, `settle`, `all` methods etc.

Comment: I heard similar concept before, that is Flow Control, are they same thing?

Comment: @CLSo not really, no. However you can think about promises in terms of flow control.

Comment: @CLSo forget to give you links for documentation http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/ - jquery deferred/promises. And https://www.promisejs.org/

Answer (score 0):

The way that I see that would make the most sense is to do nested call backs. This way everything is happening within callbacks and nothing happens until they all finish. This questions may help [wait for a jquery ajax callback from calling function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11576176/wait-for-a-jquery-ajax-callback-from-calling-function)