# how to assign function to a variable, jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function

God day, i copied this expample from [thislink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187201/return-value-from-inside-of-ajax-function) in stackoverflow and it works fine, how do i now turn it into a variable that i can use throughout the rest of my project as i have put in the exapmle below, it wont give me the values i get inside the function, it writes undefined.

```
function something(callback){

$.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        url: "http:url.com",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: 

            callback
            // console.log(data);
        //  console.log(JSON.parse(data));

            // window.location.replace("mainkedaabuild.html"+"?#"+data );
        ,
        error: function()
        {
             $('#output').html("Unable to connect");
            // window.location.replace("404kedaa.html");
        }


    });

};


    var Blue = something(function (data) {


data; return data;
```

})

```
    console.log(Blue);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: Hi Gerardo, thanks for the speedy reply, while i have read the reply and it make total sense to me, even with the example at the bottom, i am not equipt enough to write my own working solution, can you please right me one with a usable Promise!

Comment: Glad to see that the link helped you. However, the correct action here is closing your question as a duplicate.